# Server Error in '/' Application. SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-search

[image]Parser Error Message: The base type 'Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Internal.UI.SearchFarmDashboard' is not allowed for this page. The type Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Internal.UI.SearchFarmDashboard, Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c could not be found or it is not registered as safe.

Comment: What have you done on SharePoint farm recently? e.g. Windows update?

Comment: updated SharePoint to the latest version, after the update the search for new information disappeared, the old one is looking for and the new one is not

Comment: Have you run the Configuration Wizard on each server?

Comment: Is there any update?Has your database account or password changed recently?

Answer (score 0):

You might hit the newest security limitations which have been applied with June 2021 Cumulative Update.

Check your ULS-Logs for Event-ID `8gaol`.

For each third-party assembly that needs to be enabled, add an entry that has an assembly full name in the AllowAccessSensitivePropertiesAssemblies section:

```
<SharePoint>
<SafeMode>
<AllowAccessSensitivePropertiesAssemblies>
<AllowAccessSensitivePropertiesAssembly
Assembly="XXX, Version=XXX, Culture=XXX, PublicKeyToken=XXXX" />
</AllowAccessSensitivePropertiesAssemblies>

…
</SafeMode>
…
</SharePoint>
```

https://blog.stefan-gossner.com/2021/08/10/common-error-unable-to-access-this-sensitive-property-8gaol-logged-in-uls-after-installing-june-2021-cu-or-later/